# Unable to locate Signs problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What I have been having with my server the last few days is that there are massive holes all over my land; you can try jumping in them but you only go about one block down then you get stuck if you're on survival, and have to be /tp to get out. The other problem is that sometimes the server says `UNABLE TO LOCATE SIGNS` and all the stuff that I did just 5 minutess ago just vanishes. I think that's part of the holes in the ground bug.

Comment: What version is the server running? Are there any mods or plugins? Also, how does the server "say" this?

Comment: Did anything change in the last few days before this started happening?

Comment: This seems like a chunk error? Usually disconnecting and reconnecting will fix it.

Comment: The holes are chunk errors for sure

Answer (score 1):

Making sure the server software is completely up to date is always a good idea and first place to start.

I'm not sure of the problem's cause, but it's most likely server-side lag. It can be reduced by allocating more RAM to the server. Before you do this, try renaming the 'world' folder of the server. Launching it again will generate a new world. This will fix any world corruption problems.

Answer (score -1):

It's most likely server lag. I've seen this on Mineplex & Hypixel before, and whenever I see the message, I lag when I try to double jump. It's mainly server lag, but it can be something else.